# How to display asp:Label for specific amount of time

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, label

Quite simply, I want to know, if it's possible, how to display an asp:Label element for 10 seconds. Would this be a simple field in the label class, or is it a more complicated problem involving timers and what not? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is what javascript is for

Comment: My alarm clock goes off every day at 6am in the morning. Does it require a timer or is it just a simple field?

Comment: As maccettura suggested, javascript is a wonderful tool to use in this case, it has a built in function called setTimeout() which uses a value in milliseconds to know when to execute some code, you can call this function, set it's millisecond value to 10000 (10 seconds), then execute a piece of code which hides or removes your label.

Comment: @JuanR that literally makes no sense at all

Comment: Your question is the very definition of what a timer is.

Comment: @JuanR that’s false, I know what a timer is and I know I need one. I wanted to know if I need to write one myself or if asp.net takes care of it for me through setting an attribute.

Comment: Then that's how you should have phrased your question, along with some code. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with JQuery + JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#idOfYourElement').fadeOut('fast');
}, 10000); // 10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds
```

Here is pure JavaScript version:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('idOfYourElement2').style.display = 'none';
}, 10000); // 10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnp6o3fn/4/)

[Working Fiddle for Span and Images](https://jsfiddle.net/jnp6o3fn/13/)

Comment: Hmm, as JuanR said, I'm not sure this works on spans or images, and you also said "do it with JavaScript" but you used JQuery.

Comment: Does this work with spans? Also, you should mention he is going to need JQuery for your sample to work.

Comment: I’m using jQuery so that’s not an issue. Trying it now, will update.

Comment: You may find it doesn't work, depending on your styles. The reason is that spans are displayed inline by default. If that is the case, add this style to your span: `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: @JuanR yes it works on span and images. See fiddle please.

Comment: @CodingYoshi this worked great, thanks for the help. I added an answer with a few more details for future reference

Comment: @CodingYoshi your span and image fiddle is set for 1 second and you never account for the image in the "hide" logic

Comment: @maccettura Thanks. I just did not want to wait 10 seconds. As for the image, I must have copied the wrong fiddle link when I was testing. Fixed it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I understand the not wanting to wait part, but the text says it will disappear after 10 seconds and it instantly disappears.  Maybe change the text so the uninitiated wont be confused.

Comment: @maccettura done. Changed it to 10 secs so they are both the same.

Answer (score 1):

Going to throw this out there since the answer by CodingYoshi may not work on spans or images:

```
//With JQUERY
 setTimeout(function(){
   //Change the css to display none, as far as I know this works with any element
   $('#idOfYourElement').css('display', 'none');
}, 10000);

//With plain vanilla javascript
 setTimeout(function(){
   //Change the css to display none, as far as I know this works with any element
   document.getElementById('idOfYourElement').style.display = 'none';
}, 10000);
```

Comment: @CodingYoshi Cool, just thought I put my two cents in, in case yours didn't

Answer (score 0):

While Ryan Wilson's answer worked as well, I need to give the accepted answer to CodingYoshi as he answered first and the fadeOut was a little more elegant. However, just for people in the future who have this question, I did have to edit my codebehind just a little for this to work. In my case, the label started out invisible, and I wanted to make it visible and hide it again after 10 seconds. To do this, I had to call the setTimeout function from my codebehind after making the label visible by using the following:

```
labelName.Visible = true;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "labelTimer", "labelTimer();", true);
```

And in the .aspx page:

```
function labelTimer() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#labelName").fadeOut('fast');
        }, 10000);
    }
```

Inside of script tags of course. Thanks everyone for the help!